# One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version error occurs when i run the project

Tags: flutter

One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version.
Fix this issue by adding the following to C:\Users\Najeeb Khan\Desktop\codecanyon-30196044-single-market-groceryfoodpharmacy-androidiosadmin-panel-full-app-solution-with-web-site\Market_v2.1.2\customerApp\android\app\build.gradle:
android {
compileSdkVersion 31
...
}

Comment: anyone solve this error?

Answer (score 14):

It clearly says that the third-party plugin used in your project (pubspec. yaml) works only on complileSdkVersion 31. Go to your android/app/build. Gradle and change it to compileSdkVersion to 32 or higher. It may work.

Comment: whene I run sdk version 32.H e gives this error

Comment: /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/com/IWbemClassObject.dart:102:46: Error: Type 'Utf16' not found.
    Pointer obj, int lFlags, Pointer<Pointer<Utf16>> pstrObjectText);
                                             ^^^^^

Comment: Now it is the version 33.

Comment: I have change the compileSdkVersion but still get the error, while the app is working fine.

Comment: Do you know how I can check which specific plug-ins are requiring that version?

Comment: not work at all because need to re adjustment version of plugin, very much need to upgrade for working on sdk 33. this solution is not for me :(

Comment: It is recommended to use the appropriate version of plugins that require more than 32 to ensure compatibility.

Answer (score 5):

Change **compileSdkVersion** to 32 if it is 31 in

> android\app\build.gradle

Comment: Hi, Do you know how I can check which specific plug-ins are requiring that version?

Answer (score 3):

The error I got was like this:

> One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version. Fix this
> issue by adding the following to
> C:\xxx\xxx\project_name\android\app\build.gradle:
>
> android {
>
> compileSdkVersion 33
>
> ...
>
> }

In C:\xxx\xxx\project_name\android\app\build.gradle

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 33// flutter.compileSdkVersion
  ...
}
```

Comment out the old code and type 33

Answer (score 0):

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:33'
```